# How to route to sub-views in sub-directly using React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Thank you in advance.

I'm having a problem with this single-page app sub-views (AboutContact, AboutJobs, AboutPress) to display their component (views). Instead, only the about view displays.

Products and About are the only components that display correctly

**Directory Structure**

```
└── src
    ├── about
    │   ├── index.js
    │   ├── jobs.js
    │   ├── press.js
    │   └── contact.js
    ├── products
    ├── App.js
    ├── index.js
    └── index.html </root>
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    Route,
    NavLink,
    Switch,
    BrowserRouter as Router,
} from "react-router-dom";

import Home from "./home";
import About from "./about/index";
import AboutContact from "./about/contact";
import AboutJobs from "./about/jobs";
import AboutPress from "./about/press";
import Products from "./products/index";

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (<Router>
        <header>
            <ul>
                <li><NavLink to="/about">About</NavLink>
                    <ul>
                        <li><NavLink to="/about/contact">Contact</NavLink></li>
                        <li><NavLink to="/about/jobs">Jobs</NavLink></li>
                        <li><NavLink to="/about/press">Press</NavLink></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li className="primary-nav-item"><NavLink to="/products">Products</NavLink>/li>
            </ul>
        </header>
        <div className="MainContent">
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                <Switch>
                    <Route path='/about' component={About} />
                    <Route path="/about/contact" component={AboutContact} />
                    <Route path="/about/jobs" component={AboutJobs} />
                    <Route path="/about/press" component={AboutPress} />
                </Switch>
                <Route path="/products" component={Products} />
            </div>
        </Router>);
    }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Comment: Yes, I added my solution below. It's a fake scenario but explains the route enough to see how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was pretty easy and this is how to best explain it.

** ACTUAL Directory Structure **

```
└── src
    ├── about
    │   └── index.js (see below)
    │       │   └── home.js (about content)
    │       ├── jobs
    │       │   └── index.js (jobs content)         
    │       ├── press
    │       │   └── index.js (press content)
    │       └── contact
    │           └── index.js (contact content)
    ├── products
    │   └── index.js
    │       └── home.js (product content)
    ├── App.js
    ├── home.js (home content)
    ├── index.js (SPA template)
    └── index.html </root>
```

** App.js **

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    Route,
    NavLink,
    BrowserRouter as Router,
} from "react-router-dom";

import Home from "./home";
import About from "./about/index";
import AboutContact from "./about/contact";
import AboutJobs from "./about/jobs";
import AboutPress from "./about/press";
import Products from "./products/index";

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <header>
                    <NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink>
                    <NavLink to="/about">About</NavLink>
                    <NavLink to="/products">Products</NavLink>
                </header>
                <div className="MainContent">
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                    <Route path='/about' component={About} />
                    <Route path="/products" component={Products} />
                </div>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

** About **
./about/index.js

```
src
└── about
    └── index.js (contains sub-navigation and about content area
        └── home.js (contains about content)
```

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    Route,
    NavLink,
    BrowserRouter as Router,
} from "react-router-dom";

import About from "./about/index";
import AboutContact from "./about/contact";
import AboutJobs from "./about/jobs";
import AboutPress from "./about/press";

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <ul>
                    <li><NavLink to="/about">About</NavLink>
                    <li><NavLink to="/about/contact">Contact</NavLink></li>
                    <li><NavLink to="/about/jobs">Jobs</NavLink></li>
                    <li><NavLink to="/about/press">Press</NavLink></li>
                </ul>
              <div className="AboutContent">
          <Route exact path={`${ this.props.match.path}/`} component={About} / >
          <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/contact`} component={AboutContact} />
          <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/jobs`} component={AboutJobs} />
          <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/press`} component={AboutPress} />
        </div >
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

** Contact **
home (`./home.js`), about(`./about/home.js`), contact (`./about/contact/index.js`), pressroom... will all be the same as below (obviously change the class: `AboutContact` to whatever your naming convention is
./about/contact/index.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class AboutContact extends Component {
    render() {
        return (<h1>Contact</h1>);
    }
}
export default AboutContact;
```